# TeX Live 2010 and Thunderbird add-on LaTeXIt! don't cooperate

Tags: texlive, tools

I am using the Thunderbird email client on Windows and I have TeX Live 2010. I have tried the Thunderbird add-on [*LaTeXIt!*](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-us/thunderbird/addon/latex-it/) (to insert equations as images in emails). (This is not the Mac tool LaTeXiT, just to avoid confusion.)

However, the developer seems only to support MiKTeX and not TeX Live. When trying to use it in Thunderbird, e.g. putting in a simple `$a^2$`, I get an error message. The message below is from the *LaTeXIt!* tool:

```
LatexIt! run report...

*** Found expression $a^2$

$PATH is My computer path (I have deleted the info here)


*** Generating LaTeX expression:
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[latin1]{inputenx}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\begin{document}
$a^2$ %this is where your LaTeX expression goes
\end{document}

I ran C:\texlive\2010\bin\win32\latex.exe -output-directory=C:\DOCUME~1\yogcal\LOCALS~1\Temp -interaction=batchmode C:\DOCUME~1\yogcal\LOCALS~1\Temp\tblatex-1.tex error code 1

LaTeX process returned 1
Proceeding anyway...
Severe error. Missing package?
We left the .tex file there: C:\DOCUME~1\yogcal\LOCALS~1\Temp\tblatex-1.tex, try to run latex on it by yourself...
--> Failed, not inserting
```

And here is the log file

```
This is pdfTeX, Version 3.1415926-1.40.11 (Web2C 2010) (format=latex 2011.2.28)  18 JUL 2011 08:26
entering extended mode
 restricted \write18 enabled.
 %&-line parsing enabled.
**C:/DOCUME~1/yogcal/LOCALS~1/Temp/tblatex-1.tex
! Emergency stop.
 
               \protect 
 C:/DOCUME~
          1/yogcal/LOCALS~1/Temp/tblatex-1.tex
*** (job aborted, file error in nonstop mode)


Here is how much of TeX's memory you used: (info deleted here)
```

Of course, I can compile the LaTeX file `tblatex-1.tex` generated in the temp folder very well with TeX Live 2010 without any problems but *LaTeXIt!* apparently cannot.

I am posting this question here as maybe someone can provide me with useful information on what is happening during the compilation process.

Any suggestions?

---

Update:

This is what I get when running the command as *LaTeXIt!* did:

```
 C:\texlive\2010\bin\win32>latex.exe -output-directory=C:\DOCUME~1\yogcal\LOCALS~1\Temp -interaction=batchmode C:\DOCUME~1\yogcal\LOCALS~1\Temp\tblatex-1.tex
 This is pdfTeX, Version 3.1415926-1.40.11 (Web2C 2010)
 restricted \write18 enabled.
 entering extended mode
 C:\texlive\2010\bin\win32>
```

And there is no compilation.

If I move the file `tblatex-1.tex` to C:\, then compilation is fine. I believe that the error is due to the location where the file `tblatex-1.tex` is placed by *LaTeXIt!* i.e. in

```
C:\Documents and Settings\yogcal\Local Settings\Temp
```

Maybe the spacing in the folder names is creating this problem. And there is not way to change this in the option of *LaTeXIt!* to `C:\`

Comment: There's [a trobleshooting section at the author's Github](https://github.com/protz/LatexIt/wiki). Also, when you compiled the .tex file manually, did you use the same command line as the addon? That is, did you start a command prompt, then run `c:\texlive\2010\bin\win32\latex.exe -output-directory=...` as shown in the debug output?

Comment: Thanks. I have updated my post with new information and possibly what is causing this behaviour. 1 vote up.

Comment: The effort this addon is making to ensure no spaces in the folders may be unnecessary. I don't have an XP system at the moment to test on, but on one Win7 system, a command like `latex -output-directory="c:\users\me\desktop\1 2" -interaction=batchmode "c:\users\me\desktop\1 2\foo.tex"` works fine. There should be a reasonably easy fix to test in the addon code, but I'll have to look for it later.

Comment: I am trying to solve the same problem but I have got extension install problem like this: Thunderbird n'a pas pu installer le fichier situé à file:///C:/MARTIN/FTP/latex_it-0.6.xpi raison : Script d'installation non trouvé -204

Comment: The file that I have is tblatex.xpi and now it doesn't work with the latest thunderbird version 7.0.1

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The problem line appears to be in [content/main.js, line 144](https://github.com/protz/LatexIt/blob/master/content/main.js#L144) (line number accurate as of 2011/07/22, may be different in the future). Try the following steps:

1. Find the LaTeX-It xpi file. It's actually a renamed `.zip` file, so you'll need to uncompress it to edit its files. 7-Zip will extract the file without renaming, but worst case, you can rename the `.xpi` file to a `.zip` extension and then uncompress it into its own folder.
2. In the file content/main.js, replace lines 144-147 with
   `var temp_dir="c:\\temp"; temp_file = init_file(temp_dir);`
   where the first statement refers to any writable temporary folder with a simple path. Make sure to double any backslashes in the path, since Javascript uses the backslash character to escape things like newlines, tabs, etc.
3. Recompress the extracted folder into a `.zip`, then rename it to have a `.xpi` extension. Replace the old `.xpi` file with your updated one.
4. At [the author's GitHub site](https://github.com/protz/LatexIt/issues), post a bug report asking for better support of tildes in paths, or a feature request asking for the ability to override the default temporary folder with one of your choosing.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestions. This can work. However I do not know where to find the file `main.js` for the LaTeX-It plugin. 1vote up in the meantime. All there is about this plug-in is an `.xpi` file

Comment: A `.xpi` file is just a `.zip` file. Rename it if necessary (7-Zip doesn't care if you do), extract its files, make the changes, re-zip the modified contents, and rename it back to a `.xpi` extension if needed.

Comment: Thanks. With your first option, LaTeX-it can find the math expression but no compilation is done. Should there be a dot after "C\\temp"? The second option doesn't work---I get the same output as in my post.

Comment: There should at least be a semicolon after the assignment, which I'm adding to my answer now. Keep in mind I'm talking about setting the var `temp_dir` to a literal (and short) string, so lines 145-146 on the original are going to be removed entirely. So the next line would be `temp_file = init_file(temp_dir);`, and everything else would be untouched.

Comment: I have tried your first option. And it works. I presume that I need to try either your first option or your second one and NOT both.

Comment: See my `answer` for an issue that came up with the size of the image that LaTeX-it inserts.

Comment: Definitely one option or the other. Editing the answer accordingly.

Answer (score 2):

I'm the author. Both changes seem valid:

- allowing to customize the TEMP path,
- changing the default template.

If you guys could send me a pull request on GitHub (or at least send me an email with a full-fledged path), that would be fantastic.

Comment: Also if there's a way I can figure out whether I'm dealing with Miktex or Texlive, I'd like to hear about it. It would be great for that (that being setting the TEMP directory to c:\temp) to happen automatically.

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.sx!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1436/welcome-to-tex-sx) If you ask a new separate question, you'll be more likely to get an answer.

Answer (score 0):

When running the fixed code from @Mike, I could notice that LaTeX-it was returning a full page. It doesn't seem right to have say just one line of LaTeX code on a full empty page. Here is a way to fix the problem: Change the pre-existing template in LaTeX-it `"options"` to the following instead:

```
 \documentclass[12pt]{article}
 \pagestyle{empty}
 \parindent=0pt
 \usepackage[latin1]{inputenx}
 \usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
 \begin{document}
  __REPLACEME__ %this is where your LaTeX expression goes
 \end{document}
```

This template will give a cropped page size tightly wrapped about the LaTeX expression.

`Note: This is not an answer to my original question but this issue has come up after LaTeX-it began working thanks to the solution of @Mike. And I have accepted his solution.`